# How I echo this kind of array in php?

Tags: php

I do have an array something like below:

```
[images] => Array
(
        [0] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 1
                        [path] => ../images/properties/1/1447053991.jpg
                )

        [1] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 3
                        [path] => ../images/properties/1/1447054231.jpg
                )

        [2] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 4
                        [path] => ../images/properties/1/1447054666.jpg
                )

        [3] => Array
                (
                        [id] => 17
                        [path] => ../images/properties/1/1447141341.jpg
                )

)
```

When I need to echo this array, I want to add different HTML for first key of this array and also different HTML for other keys.

This is how I tried it:

```
foreach($property['images'] as $image) {
    //echo '<pre>',print_r($image).'</pre>';
    if ($image['id'] != '') {                   
        $html  .= " <a href='".$image['path']."' class='image-wrap' title='' rel='prettyPhoto'>\n";
        $html  .= "     <img src='".$image['path']."' alt=''/>\n";
        $html  .= "     <span class='zoom-icon'></span>\n";
        $html  .= " </a>\n";
    } else {
        $html  .= " <a href='".$image['path']."' title='1' rel='prettyPhoto[group]'></a>\n";
    }
}
```

But its not working for me. Hope somebody may help me out.

Comment: How "not working" ? What do you see when uncomment print_r($image) ?

Comment: What are the errors you get? Does it show something? Do you expect this to also print? ... Please be more precise with your question.

Comment: How could this be? If $property['images'] is the same array as you printed above then there is no way it would not print the $image['path'] value...

Comment: When  I print this array I want to display first image of the array and but other images should be echo in a anchor tag, like I do it in the `else part` of my code.

Comment: @user3733831what does $image prints when you uncomment the print_r($image) in foreach..

Comment: It prints all images like this `Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [path] => ../images/properties/1/1447053991.jpg
)
1`

Comment: @user3733831 echo $image['id']; and print what you get

Comment: @BasheerKharoti, This image array comes from a multidimensional array - `foreach($properties as $propery_id => $property) {
 // ... stuff
 foreach($property['images'] as $image) {
  // ... stuff
 }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong your foreach is printing values as expected and you want the first index to print out something different then others..

```
foreach($property['images'] as $index => $image) {
   //echo '<pre>',print_r($image).'</pre>';
   if ($index == 0) {                   
     // do stuff for the first index
   } else {
     // do stuff for other indexes
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

since you want to display `first image` as image and the rest in anchor tag try this.use a `counter` to identify `first` and the `rest`.there can be two cases.

**case 1:** when your index does not start with `0`.

```
$property=array('images' => Array
(
        '0' => Array
                (
                        'id' => 1,
                        'path' => '../images/properties/1/1447053991.jpg'
                ),

        '1' => Array
                (
                        'id' => 3,
                        'path' =>'../images/properties/1/1447054231.jpg'
                )
        )
        );


$html="";
$counter=0;
foreach($property['images'] as $image) {
    if ($image['id'] != '') {
        if($counter == 0){
            $html  .= "     <img src='".$image['path']."' alt=''/>\n";
            $counter++;
        }else{
        $html  .= " <a href='".$image['path']."' class='image-wrap' title='' rel='prettyPhoto'>".$image['id']."\n";

        $html  .= "     <span class='zoom-icon'></span>\n";
        $html  .= " </a>\n";
        }
    } else {
        $html  .= " <a href='".$image['path']."' title='1' rel='prettyPhoto'group''></a>\n";
    }
}


echo $html;
?>
```

**case 2:** when index starts from `0`.

```
foreach($property['images'] as $key=>$image) {
        if ($image['id'] != '') {
            if($key == 0){
                $html  .= "     <img src='".$image['path']."' alt=''/>\n";
            }else{
            $html  .= " <a href='".$image['path']."' class='image-wrap' title='' rel='prettyPhoto'>".$image['id']."\n";

            $html  .= "     <span class='zoom-icon'></span>\n";
            $html  .= " </a>\n";
            }
        } else {
            $html  .= " <a href='".$image['path']."' title='1' rel='prettyPhoto'group''></a>\n";
        }
    }
```